# The Robber in the Agency

Tags: logical-deduction, story, mystery

> Special agent John Washington looked at the four men standing across him. “We are going to get Devious Dan this time,” The FBI man growled. “Dead or alive.”
>
> The men nodded and jumped on to their vehicle and drove off amid the thunderous rain. The tip had come from an old man who had seen a man holed up in a shack at the Great Canyon. He had identified him as Devious Dan from the FBI’s most wanted posters he had been shown.
>
> All four men sat in silence as Washington drove the car through the heavy rain. Devious Dan had robbed 10 banks and killed almost half a dozen security guards in his five-month crime spree.
>
> Joe Morris dug around in his pockets, his hand brushing his .32 revolver. He found his pack of cigarettes and offered it to Chester Harrison, who was sitting next to him.
>
> Chester shook his head. “Don’t smoke.” Joe remarked that these young men are all into clean living, and then thrust the pack back into his pocket.
>
> Then, George Franklin asked him, “How long have you been into law enforcement”?
>
> Joe snorted, “I am retiring at the end of the year. My wife and I brought a nice old cottage in the countryside. We are set for an easy life.”
>
> Matt Jameson, shoving his .32,  commented, “Not bad, old guy. As for me, I got some things to take care of before I turn in my badge. I have a few debts to take care of, but who doesn’t these days.”
>
> George grunted, “I have 4 kids to raise with my meager salary,” he said, balancing a Thompson sub-machine gun.
>
> Young Chester was in his first man hunt and was visibly nervous keeping his shotgun close to him.
>
> An hour later, they had reached the place. Washington commanded George to go around and cover the back in case Dan tried to jump out of the window. John then cocked his .45 automatic revolver at the door of a shack.
>
> “Put your hands up, Dan. It’s the end!” he roared. At first Dan couldn’t believe his eyes.
>
> Then, in the fire, the lantern hanging overhead shattered on the floor. Darkness engulfed the shack. Heavy gunfire erupted. Chester lit the lantern that he had been told to bring illuminating the shack. The silence was now deafening. The men looked at the bullet-ridden body of Devious Dan and at the crisp green money of the banks lying on the floor.
>
> Joe had a slug in the gut, Washington got one on the shoulder. George had been hit in his left ear. He was still outside the shack in the back, but his gun lay inside, while Matt Jameson said he got hit on the thigh.
>
> The Chief remarked, “You can now come in, Chester.” The young man was standing outside the shack, clearly frightened by the ensuing carnage.
>
> John Washington then remarked, “We got a lot of men shot at considering that Devious Dan never fired a single shot!”

Clearly, someone else was after the bank loot beside Devious Dan.
**Can you find out who it was?**

Comment: Is knowledge of the particulars for each of those weapons required to discern what happened?

Comment: @EngineerToast Yes, not much, just some general knowledge about the guns..

Comment: I'm not sure about "too broad" but I do wonder whether there is actually enough information in the question to yield an unambiguous answer. We'll see...

Comment: Incidentally, the story doesn't seem to make a great deal of sense -- whoever our perpetrator is, (1) he needs to have been confident of killing Dan and four armed FBI agents, and (2) he needs to have misjudged this incredibly badly (since in the event only Dan is dead and only Joe is seriously wounded). He needs to have thought it easier to murder his colleagues at the shack when they're all ready to fight rather than afterwards. And now we're supposed to do some fancy deduction when at the actual scene the question would have been "OK, guys, let's check how many shots you've fired"...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan The answer, as I have prepared, can be thought out from the information in the question. As for the ambiguity part, That's your perspective once you see the answer

Comment: Of course it's only a puzzle, but in a puzzle that depends to some extent on reckoning plausibility (could such-and-such a gun have produced such-and-such effects, etc.) it bothers me a little when other features of the story seem entirely implausible.

Comment: I should add that I have never been involved in anything remotely like an FBI stakeout and maybe it's all more plausible than it sounds to me.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No, the thing is all of them were looking to kill Dan and hence, would have fired in the Darkness. The number of shots doesn't matter because Dan's body was riddled with bullets..

Comment: Oh, so we're supposed to understand that they were all firing? Fair enough. (I still don't see how any of them could have thought they'd be able to kill all the others and get away, though. Never mind, I'm just nitpicking.)

Answer (score 3):

> Nobody. It was the gun on the floor.

It was mentioned that somebody's gun was on the floor (not clear to me who's), and that a lantern fell and smashed on the floor. So

> the heat of the exploding lantern set off the gun.

Comment: Good try, but the gun fell after the lantern had hit the floor. So, Not the answer..

Comment: I guess that this would be more correct with a [lateral-thinking] tag...

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comment about knowing basics about the guns I would suggest

> John did it

Because

> He cocked an automatic revolver at the door.  Wikipedia tells "**An automatic revolver (more correctly, a semi-automatic revolver) is a revolver that uses the energy of firing for cocking the hammer and revolving the cylinder**".  So it's possible this action of cocking was actually firing at the door.

Although

> I guess you would need to cock the gun manually the first time so this is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

It was:

> George

Because:

> George had been hit in his left ear. He was still outside the shack in the back but his gun lay inside- suggests that George wanted Dan to be dead at any cost so he hit Dan inspite he was asked to stay outside. There is also reference that George had been hit in his left ear. This also suggests that he went inside during the firing

Comment: You could use the spoiler (>!) while answering the question...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> Chester as he was the only one with the shotgun 
>  A slug can only come from a shotgun 
>  'Joe had a 'slug' ' Washington got one on the shoulder'
>  These quotes prove that Chester shot the two of them